# Bags of visual words - counter intuitive result

Tags: image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm reading the frequently-cited paper [Bags of Binary words for Fast Place Recognition in Image Sequences](http://doriangalvez.com/papers/GalvezTRO12.pdf) and have found something strange in the paper. The similarity measure is presented as:

$s(v_1, v_2) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}|\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}-\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}|$

where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are bag-of-word vectors. Now, suppose $image_1$ contains 100 occurrences of a certain word and $image_2$ contains just one occurrence. Because $\frac{v_1}{|v_1|} = 1$ and $\frac{v_2}{|v_2|} = 1$, wouldn't $s(v_1,v_2) = 1$ even when the two images are very different? That's a rather counter-intuitive result.